# Django Rest Framework - how to save data based on foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I'm working on an app where a user uploads a file.  The user chooses a "Project" to assign the file to.  Each project is assigned a "user" and an "editor".  When the file is uploaded, I'm trying to set the owner of the file based on the "user" from the "project".

Project Model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    projectCode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    projectName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name="projects", on_delete=models.CASCADE,  null=True)
    editor = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    completedDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    dueDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.projectName}"
```

Model for the file being uploaded:

```
class Completed(models.Model):
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    handle = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    size = models.IntegerField()
    source = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    uploadId = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    originalPath = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name="completed", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project, related_name="projectId", on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=1)
    uploadDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    editor = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name="editor", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.filename}"
```

Project Serializer:
class

```
ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'
```

Serializer for file uploaded:

```
class CompletedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    project = ProjectSerializer(read_only=True)
    owner = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    editor = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Completed
        fields = '__all__'
```

And finally, the viewset for the uploaded file:

```
class CompletedViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]

    serializer_class = CompletedSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Completed.objects.all().filter(Q(project__user=self.request.user)
                                                  | Q(project__editor=self.request.user))
        return queryset

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(
            editor=self.request.user
            owner=???????
        )
```

How can I save the owner based on the "user" from the Project model?

Comment: You're setting read_only=True for all the serializers in your view sets, which means the  information about the current context(about the file change) won't be deserialized. Have a look at: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments

Comment: Thanks for that. Maybe write-only or source will do the trick for me there.  But I'm still unsure of how to take the "user" value from the "projects" model and set it as the "owner" of the file upload in the serializer.save function.  I haven't been able to find any documentation that helps me figure that out.